# Prove monotonicity of an implicit function arising in sampling theory

Tags: probability, statistics, implicit-function

Let $t_{n-1, \alpha/2}$ denote the critical point (upper tail probability of $\alpha/2$) of the [Student's T distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution) with $n-1$ degrees-of-freedom.  I am examining the function:

$$w(\alpha, n) = \frac{t_{n-1, \alpha/2}}{\sqrt{n}}
\quad \quad \quad
\text{for all } 0 <\alpha <1 \text{ and } n > 1.$$

From statistical reasoning, plus graphical analysis of the function, I am convinced that this function is monotonically decreasing in $n$ (which is equivalent to $\sqrt{n}$ increasing faster than $t_{n-1, \alpha/2}$).  I would like to prove this fact by showing that:

$$\frac{\partial w}{\partial n} (\alpha, n) < 0.$$

I have tried various methods to do this (implicit differentiation, looking at finite differences, etc.) and I have been unable to crack it so far.  Would any of you mathematics gurus like to have a go?